# Indenting c++ in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2005

I am using Visual Studio 2005 team edition. I come from a unix background using gvim.
It would appear that formatting/indenting code seems to be a lot harder.
Can anyone suggest a good option. VI with its autoindent/smartindent settings spoilt me. 
thanks

Answer (score 2):

ctrl K-F formats the selected code

Go to tools->options->Text editor->c/c++ to set formatting details

Comment: This doesn't come close to what vim does for you byu  way of indenting. It is entirely possible I am doing something wrong, but I have already tried this without the desired affect.

Comment: Sorry - I didn't invent it! It's good enough to spot a missed "}", you can always use Vim, make and the VC++ compiler from the commandline.   There might be code reformatting plugins but I can't recommend anything